# How can I make a navigation bar that converts to a button for a sidebar when scaled down too much?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have seen many sites with a navigation bar that will convert to a button that opens a menu if the page is scaled down too much. An example of this: www.aurelswonderland.com (Scale the windows width down and watch the nav bar dissapear)

How can I implement this myself?

Comment: They are most probably using some form of [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com). It's a framework for making responsive websites. That website uses CSS `@media` queries to check the width of the window. If it is less than a certain amount, it will hide the nav bar and show the button

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: I tried the following: @media (width: 903px) {
    .nav {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
} 

However, the navigation bar wont dissapear when the browser is scaled to less than 903.

Comment: @VenomzHD I think its, `@media screen and (max-width: 903px) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are using Bootstrap or Foundation, I like to use SlickNav. It's a jQuery plugin that's very easy to use. You just call the slicknav() function on the "ul" in your navigation and you're good to go. You can also pass in options as in most jQuery plugins.

http://slicknav.com/